# Template parse errors: There is no directive with “exportAs” set to “matMenu”

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running unit test for angular app. I am getting

```
Component should create FAILED
        Error: Template parse errors:
        There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("
                  <span flex>{{dateRange}}</span>
                </button>
                <mat-menu [ERROR ->]#menu="matMenu">
                  <button *ngFor="let dataRange of dataRanges" (click)="onDateRange(dataRan"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TransactionsComponent.html@18:18
        There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("customFilterData">Custom ></button>
                </mat-menu>
                <mat-menu class="date-range-menu" [ERROR ->]#dateTimeMenu="matMenu">
                  <ngbd-datepicker-range style="font-size:16px;font-family:ffunit;""): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TransactionsComponent.html@22:42
        There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("
                  <span flex>Add filter</span>
                </button>
                <mat-menu style="width:50px;" [ERROR ->]#menuFilter="matMenu">
                  <button *ngFor="let header of filterHeaders; let i = index" (click)"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TransactionsComponent.html@31:38
            at syntaxError (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1275:17)
            at TemplateParser.parse (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:15084:19)
            at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24272:37)
            at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24259:23)
            at eval (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24202:62)
            at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at JitCompiler._compileComponents (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24202:19)
            at eval (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24120:19)
            at Object.then (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1266:77)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24118:26)
        Error: Template parse errors:
        There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("
                  <span flex>{{dateRange}}</span>
                </button>
                <mat-menu [ERROR ->]#menu="matMenu">
                 ......
                 ......bla bla ....
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Angular/cli version is 7.3.8 and  in angular module I have import { MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';

Comment: still there is a problem

Comment: You need to add MatMenuModule to the imports array of your TestBed configuration.

Comment: Cool that works but I have one question, should the template parse error be ignored as I have added NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in TestBedConfig

Comment: Different devs have different opinions on `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`.  Personally, I never use it since it masks what could be issues that I want to know about and correct.  I want to fix the errors and get a clean test, not ignore them.

Comment: Cool, thank you!!!